# Understanding the relationship between type inference and target type

Tags: java

In the code snippet below, I would like to know why `var.get("key").getClass()` returns `java.lang.Integer` instead of `java.lang.Object` since the method's parameter `var` is of type `Map<String, Object>` :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    useHashMap(new HashMap<>());

}

public static void useHashMap(Map<String, Object> var) {
    var.put("key", 1);      
    System.out.println(var.get("key").getClass()); //prints : class java.lang.Integer
}
```

Comment: You have an `Integer` object in an `Object` variable. `getClass()` returns the run-time type of the object, not the type of the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly how it supposed to be.

`getClass()` returns the actual class of run-time object, as javadoc says:

```
/**
     * Returns the runtime class of this {@code Object}. The returned
     * {@code Class} object is the object that is locked by {@code
     * static synchronized} methods of the represented class.
     *
     * <p><b>The actual result type is {@code Class<? extends |X|>}
     * where {@code |X|} is the erasure of the static type of the
     * expression on which {@code getClass} is called.</b> For
     * example, no cast is required in this code fragment:</p>
     *
     * <p>
     * {@code Number n = 0;                             }<br>
     * {@code Class<? extends Number> c = n.getClass(); }
     * </p>
     *
     * @return The {@code Class} object that represents the runtime
     *         class of this object.
     * @jls 15.8.2 Class Literals
     */
    public final native Class<?> getClass();
```

Another example is:

```
Object o = 1;
System.out.println(o.getClass());
```

Output:

```
class java.lang.Integer
```

The type of **reference** is `Object`, the type of **run-time object** is `Integer`.

The same situation when you are using interface reference type:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println(list.getClass());
```

Output:

```
class java.util.ArrayList
```

The reference type here is `List`, however it's an interface without implementation. The actual run-time object here is `ArraysList`.